# Get a Video URL on a Web when I click the PLAY button. Then using Python3 to download it

Tags: python-3.x, video, download, automation

I want to download a Video on a CNN's website using Python 3 automatically. 
The address is https://edition.cnn.com/cnn10 .

Every weekday the CNN will put a video on that website.
I know how to find the video's real URL using Chrome browser manually:

1. Open the adress in Chrome browser, then press F12, like this:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNO1N.png)
2. Choosing the label of Network, then click the PLAY button to start playing the video, like this:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfIlm.png)
3. Then I can get the real URL, like this:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xySh.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en5S3.png)

The video real URL is https://pmd.cdn.turner.com/cnn/big/cnn10/2018/09/13/caption/ten-0914.cnn_2253601_768x432_1300k.mp4

Using the following python 3 code can download that video:

```
import requests

print("Download is start!")

url = 'https://pmd.cdn.turner.com/cnn/big/cnn10/2018/09/13/caption/ten-0914.cnn_2253601_768x432_1300k.mp4'
r = requests.get(url, stream = True)

with open('20180914.mp4', "wb") as mp4:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 768*432):
        if chunk:
            mp4.write(chunk)

print("Download over!")
```

**My problem is how to get that URL using Python or any other automatic ways?** Because I want to download automatically those different videos every weekday.

What works I have already did:

I am looking for a solution on the Internet but failed.

Then I got some video's URL and try to find a regular pattern about these URL, like this:
https://pmd.cdn.turner.com/cnn/big/cnn10/2018/09/11/caption/ten-0912.cnn_2250840_768x432_1300k.mp4
https://pmd.cdn.turner.com/cnn/big/cnn10/2018/09/10/caption/ten-0911.cnn_2249562_768x432_1300k.mp4

Obviously, the date is related to every weekday, but there is 7 "random" numbers in url. I still can not understand these numbers now!

Any Help will be appreciated !

Thank you !

Comment: https://pmd.cdn.turner.com/cnn/big/cnn10/2018/09/11/caption/ten-0912.cnn_2250840_768x432_1300k.mp4
https://pmd.cdn.turner.com/cnn/big/cnn10/2018/09/10/caption/ten-0911.cnn_2249562_768x432_1300k.mp4
https://pmd.cdn.turner.com/cnn/big/cnn10/2018/09/09/caption/ten-0910.cnn_2248628_768x432_1300k.mp4
https://pmd.cdn.turner.com/cnn/big/cnn10/2018/09/06/caption/ten-0907.cnn_2245399_768x432_1300k.mp4
https://pmd.cdn.turner.com/cnn/big/cnn10/2018/09/05/caption/ten-0906.cnn_2244052_768x432_1300k.mp4

Comment: Is the video link not mentioned in the source code of that page?

Comment: Yes. Before I click the PLAY button, there is not the link which I want in the source code of the page.